# Quick actions inside the app like iOS files app

Tags: ios, swift, quickaction

I want to implement quick actions like native **Files** application, on long press any item quick action view appears. Is there anything available in **iOS** to achieve it. I have attached some screenshots for better understanding. I know about Quick actions on home screen, I only want to achieve such thing inside my App not on AppIcon tap.

[image: iOS Files App]

[image: long press on image/file]
[image: long press on folder]

Comment: It's called a _menu_ (or _context menu_). See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/adding_context_menus_in_your_app

Answer (score 0):

It's called a context menu. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/adding_context_menus_in_your_app

1. For Tableview you can implement like below. when long press it will be invoked

   ```
   - (nullable UIContextMenuConfiguration *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView contextMenuConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath point:(CGPoint)point  API_AVAILABLE(ios(13.0)) {
    UIContextMenuConfiguration *config = [UIContextMenuConfiguration configurationWithIdentifier:@"MenuControls" previewProvider:nil  actionProvider:^UIMenu * _Nullable(NSArray<UIMenuElement *> * _Nonnull suggestedActions) {

        NSMutableArray *actions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [actions addObject:[UIAction actionWithTitle:@"Copy" image:[UIImage systemImageNamed:@"doc.on.doc.fill"] identifier:nil handler:^(__kindof UIAction * _Nonnull action) {
            // Do corresponding action based on menu item
            [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string = @"Sample Data";
        }]];

        if (@available(iOS 14.0, *)) {
            UIMenu *menu = [UIMenu menuWithChildren:actions];
            return menu;
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            UIMenu *menu = [UIMenu menuWithTitle:@"Actions" children:actions];
            return menu;
        }
    }];

    return config;
   }
   ```
2. For collection view same can be achieved by using below method

   ```
   - (nullable UIContextMenuConfiguration *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView contextMenuConfigurationForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath point:(CGPoint)point API_AVAILABLE(ios(13.0)) API_UNAVAILABLE(watchos, tvOS);
   ```

https://kylebashour.com/posts/ios-13-context-menus